# dynamic array container with unitialised elements possibility

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I am populating network data buffer for sockets `send()` call.
Initially i know buffer `maximumSize`, and (after populating it) i know `finalSize <= maximumSize`.
I feel convenient having possibility to shrink such a buffer, making it smaller, leaving data as is.

1) I want use container, storing the size along (`like std::vector< char > or std::string`)

2) There is no need to memset allocated buffer bytes to zero or any other known value.

I want to satisfy 1 and 2.
What container can you advise me and why?

Comment: [`std::vector` with a neat trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149665/c-vector-that-doesnt-initialize-its-members) - in the accepted answer.

Comment: thanks for info, i was not able to find related topics here by myself.

Comment: In a crunch you could use a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[MAX])` and keep track of the actual size.

Comment: I dont want my program to "crunch". unique_ptr seems totally unsuitable solution here, as it violates requirement #1 of my post