# vector::reserve and built-in types

Tags: c++, vector

*Please don't mark this as duplicate without having read it as a whole. This is not a "what does std::reserve do" question.*

Is it an error to write to a vector::reserve'd address with built-in types?

```
vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(10);
vec[5] = 24; // Is this an error?
```

I understand that objects aren't initialized but since those are just **integers** and space is allocated by reserve and this is done in **contiguous storage**, is this an error at all?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149665/c-vector-that-doesnt-initialize-its-members/11150052#11150052

Comment: This is actually "what does `std::reserve` do". If you understood that, you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't care for the downvotes. Especially because there are answers down there upvoted and wrong - that means people do not have this concept clear and therefore this is a perfectly valid question. I couldn't find a duplicate that precisely answers my issue.

Comment: IMO this is a perfectly legitimate question. I believe that downvoters did not really understood it.

Comment: @sbabbi It is legitimate and it has been asked before. Including by OP, earlier.

Comment: @juanchopanza negative. I **tried** to ask it before but lazy people who didn't read it as a whole marked it as a duplicate. I decided to keep the question since somebody already asked it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an error because it is undefined behavior, according to the standard. This may not result in any observable problems, but it is still an error. Some implementations will do bounds checking and throw an exception in debug mode. They can do that, and it is perfectly standard compliant to do so, because you invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: This makes sense. The size didn't change afterall.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is an error.

And this is also the difference between `vector::reserve` and `vector::resize`.  As you have said, it has to with the the vector element being unitialised.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve) excellent thread on SO for a difference between the two.

Comment: By "object" you mean the vector itself right?

Comment: Yes, the vector isn't initialised. And even if it is, but has a current size of say 5 with reserve space 20, doing vec[10] will give an error.

Comment: @therainmaker: No, the vector is not uninitialized, the element is.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley : Nice distinction. Never really thought that way. Editing it.

Comment: @therainmaker: Even with that caveat, it doesn't really get to the point, since we are talking about POD types here. And assigning to POD types qualifies as initializing them. So if the only problem was that `reserve` didn't initialize the elements, then what the OP is doing wouldn't be an error for a vector of POD types (like int).